# How do you create an asynchronous method in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Every blog post I've read tells you how to consume an asynchronous method in C#, but for some odd reason never explain how to build your own asynchronous methods to consume. So I have this code right now that consumes my method:

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var now = await CountToAsync(1000);
    label1.Text = now.ToString();
}
```

And I wrote this method that is `CountToAsync`:

```cs
private Task<DateTime> CountToAsync(int num = 1000)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("#{0}", i);
        }
    }).ContinueWith(x => DateTime.Now);
}
```

**Is this, the use of `Task.Factory`, the best way to write an asynchronous method, or should I write this another way?**

Comment: I'm asking a general question about how to structure a method. I just want to know where to start in turning my already synchronous methods into asynchronous ones.

Comment: OK, so what does a typical synchronous method *do*, and *why do you want to make it asynchronous*?

Comment: Let's say I have to batch process a bunch of files and return a result object.

Comment: OK, so: (1) what is the high-latency operation: obtaining the files -- because the network could be slow, or whatever -- or doing the processing -- because it is CPU intensive, say.  And (2) you still haven't said why you want it to be asynchronous in the first place. Is there a UI thread that you want to not block, or what?

Comment: @EricLippert The example give by the op is very basic, it really doesn't need to be that complicated.

Comment: Agreed with David. @EricLipper, I really feel this is perfect question with reasonable details.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

I don't recommend `StartNew` unless you need that level of complexity.

If your async method is dependent on other async methods, the easiest approach is to use the `async` keyword:

```
private static async Task<DateTime> CountToAsync(int num = 10)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  }

  return DateTime.Now;
}
```

If your async method is doing CPU work, you should use `Task.Run`:

```
private static async Task<DateTime> CountToAsync(int num = 10)
{
  await Task.Run(() => ...);
  return DateTime.Now;
}
```

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: @Stephen: "If your async method is dependanton other async methods" - ok, but what if that is not the case.  What if were trying to wrap some code that calls BeginInvoke with some callback code?

Comment: @Ricibob: You should use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` to wrap `BeginInvoke`. Not sure what you mean about "callback code"; feel free to post your own question with code.

Comment: Stephen, in the for loop, is the next iteration called immediately or after the `Task.Delay` returns?

Comment: @jp2code: `await` is an "asynchronous wait", so it does not proceed to the next iteration until after the task returned by `Task.Delay` completes.

Comment: @StephenCleary Nice answer, and nice blog too. +10 :)

Comment: Another great [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177.aspx) on the subject that was very helpful to me.

Comment: This is very nice to use sync methods in async mode. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 16):

If you didn't want to use async/await inside your method, but still "decorate" it so as to be able to use the await keyword from outside, [TaskCompletionSource.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1):

```
public static Task<T> RunAsync<T>(Func<T> function)
{ 
    if (function == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(“function”); 
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(); 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>          
    { 
        try 
        {  
           T result = function(); 
           tcs.SetResult(result);  
        } 
        catch(Exception exc) { tcs.SetException(exc); } 
   }); 
   return tcs.Task; 
}
```

[From here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/06/02/the-nature-of-taskcompletionsourcetresult/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177(v=vs.110).aspx)

> To support such a paradigm with Tasks, we need a way to retain the Task façade and the ability to refer to an arbitrary asynchronous operation as a Task, but to control the lifetime of that Task according to the rules of the underlying infrastructure that’s providing the asynchrony, and to do so in a manner that doesn’t cost significantly. This is the purpose of TaskCompletionSource.

I saw it's also used in the .NET source, e.g. [WebClient.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,c113b360583ad964):

```
    [HostProtection(ExternalThreading = true)]
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public Task<string> UploadStringTaskAsync(Uri address, string method, string data)
    {
        // Create the task to be returned
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(address);

        // Setup the callback event handler
        UploadStringCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (sender, e) => HandleCompletion(tcs, e, (args) => args.Result, handler, (webClient, completion) => webClient.UploadStringCompleted -= completion);
        this.UploadStringCompleted += handler;

        // Start the async operation.
        try { this.UploadStringAsync(address, method, data, tcs); }
        catch
        {
            this.UploadStringCompleted -= handler;
            throw;
        }

        // Return the task that represents the async operation
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Finally, I also found the following useful:

> I get asked this question all the time. The implication is that there must be some thread somewhere that’s blocking on the I/O call to the external resource. So, asynchronous code frees up the request thread, but only at the expense of another thread elsewhere in the system, right? No, not at all.
>
> To understand why asynchronous requests scale, I’ll trace a (simplified) example of an asynchronous I/O call. Let’s say a request needs to write to a file. The request thread calls the asynchronous write method. WriteAsync is implemented by the Base Class Library (BCL), and uses completion ports for its asynchronous I/O. So, the WriteAsync call is passed down to the OS as an asynchronous file write. The OS then communicates with the driver stack, passing along the data to write in an I/O request packet (IRP).
>
> This is where things get interesting: If a device driver can’t handle an IRP immediately, it must handle it asynchronously. So, the driver tells the disk to start writing and returns a “pending” response to the OS. The OS passes that “pending” response to the BCL, and the BCL returns an incomplete task to the request-handling code. The request-handling code awaits the task, which returns an incomplete task from that method and so on. Finally, the request-handling code ends up returning an incomplete task to ASP.NET, and the request thread is freed to return to the thread pool.

[Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802603.aspx)

If the target is to improve scalability (rather than responsiveness), it all relies on the existence of an external I/O that provides the opportunity to do that.

Comment: If you will see the comment above the [Task.Run implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,298c51c20d5a4fad) e.g. _Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a Task handle for that work_. You actually do the same. I'm sure that Task.Run will be better, cause it internally manage CancelationToken and makes some optimizations with scheduling and run options.

Comment: so what you did with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem could be done with Task.Run , right?

Comment: Its a best practice to use Task.Run instead of "do it yourself" via ThreadPool.  Also, ThreadPool is an old school approach; hence the need to use TaskCompletionSource<T>.

Answer (score 8):

One very simple way to make a method asynchronous is to use Task.Yield() method. As MSDN states:

> You can use await Task.Yield(); in an asynchronous method to force the
>   method to complete asynchronously.

Insert it at beginning of your method and it will then return immediately to the caller and complete the rest of the method on another thread.

```
private async Task<DateTime> CountToAsync(int num = 1000)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("#{0}", i);
    }
    return DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: In a WinForms application the rest of the method will complete in the same thread (the UI thread). The `Task.Yield()` is indeed useful, for the cases that you want to ensure that the returned `Task` will not be immediately completed upon creation.