# How to create two process and run them simultaneously in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi

I want create two process let's say  process A and process B .

And I want to run them Simultaneously .

How to do it if at all it is possible ?

Comment: Use `asynchronous` method

Comment: unlike in unix we can create a child process with fork() As iam new to C#, i Just wanted to know what is the respective method to create a process in C#

Comment: Use `asynchronous` method [See this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063520/how-do-you-create-a-async-method-in-c-sharp-5

Comment: @Venkat `async` is useless here. You just need `Process.Start`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Masih's post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514250/masih-akbari) i got some idea and came up with this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace proces
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            create_process__A("Balotelli");
            create_process__B("Pirlo");
        }

         static void create_process__A(string t)
        {
            Process.Start("http://google.com/search?q=" + t);

        }
         static void create_process__B(string t)
         {
             Process.Start("http://google.com/search?q=" + t);

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to declare the methods `async`. You do not `await` anywhere.

Comment: yes ...you are right ....

Answer (score 1):

I write a Little Sample for you That You Can Use:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(A));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(B));
    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
    }

    static void A()
    {
    }

    static void B()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to create it with Process ...any way you gave me some idea s to work on and i think i got it ....Thanks