# Async methods on Sap .Net Connector 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm using SAP .Net Connector 3.0.0.42 in my C# .Net v4.5 applications. So far, I can use it with no problems like this:

```
var destination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(destinationName);
var repository = destination.Repository;
var function = repository.CreateFunction(functionName);
function.Invoke(destination);
var resultTable = function.GetTable(tableName);  //This can be time consuming
```

Sometimes, there are calls that are time consuming and because they are IO bound operations I want to make it `async`, for not blocking the thread while waiting to complete, but the `Sap .Net Connector` doesn't expose any async methods (as far I know).

I read about [producing async/await methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063520/how-do-you-create-a-async-method-in-c-sharp-5) and the [Task-based async pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177(v=vs.110).aspx), but to use that I need low level `async` methods to propagate up, right? For instance, changing from `Thread.Sleep` to `Task.Delay`. But, what if there are no such methods?

My first thought was to use `Task.Run` but I read that it's for CPU bound operations, and using that it'll pick up another thread and block it, so it's not really `async`. Also, if I develop an asp.net app will take another thread from the pool, isn't it?

So, my question is if **it is possible to wrap sync IO bound methods in `async` ones?** I really think I'm missing something here... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is no native support within the plugin, but as suggested by Case Ahr [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3348045) you can do it within your project.