# how to avoid delay after use text to speech function in c#

Tags: c#

how to avoid delay after use text to speech function in c#, how to avoid  delay after SpeechSynthesizer.speak , i would like to my timer enable immediately.

```
SpeechSynthesizer sr = new SpeechSynthesizer();
sr.Rate = 1;
sr.Volume = 100;
sr.Speak("mytext");
timer1.enabled=true; /*how to run this line immediately, not wating for    sr.speak */
```

Comment: You should read on a little bit about async.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16064191/3718147

Comment: but i use this code in a function that change the gui and then the gui change after sr.speak, i need to Synchroniz it,

Comment: You should read the link that @bladespinner posted

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an asynchronous version of Speak. If this is not available, then you can create a thread to run Speak in the background.

```
SpeechSynthesizer sr = new SpeechSynthesizer();
sr.Rate = 1;
sr.Volume = 100;

//the following starts a background thread
Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () =>
     {
        //this anon method will be run in a background thread
        sr.Speak();
        SpeakCallBack();
     });
```

When defining `SpeakCallBack` make sure to `Invoke` any UI code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void speakSomething(string message)
{
  SpeechSynthesizer sr = new SpeechSynthesizer();
  sr.Rate = 1;
  sr.Volume = 100;
  await sr.Speak(message);
}
```

Then, in your main function or whichever method just now...

```
speakSomething("my text");
timer1.enabled=true;
```