# What is wrong using Async and Await in this WPF example?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm new to await async, I want to make sense of what I studied about the subject in this real scenario:

I have a simple code that reads bitcoin price which takes 1-2 seconds, I don't want to lock the UI using await async and still give a status if it is loading or done:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> bitcoinPriceTask = GetBitcoinPrice();
        lblStatus.Content = "Loading...";
    }

    protected async Task<int> GetBitcoinPrice()
    {
        IPriceRetrieve bitcoin = new BitcoinPrice();
        string price = bitcoin.GetStringPrice();
        txtResult.Text = price;
        lblStatus.Content = "Done";
        return 1;
    }
```

as requested, here is the implementation of BitcoinPrice class:

```
public class BitcoinPrice : IPriceRetrieve
{
    public BitcoinPrice()
    {
        Url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin%20price";
    }

    public string Url { get; }


    public string GetStringPrice()
    {
        var html = RetrieveContent();
        html = MetadataUtil.GetFromTags(html, "1 Bitcoin = ", " US dollars");
        return html;
    }

    public float GetPrice()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string RetrieveContent()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(Url);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return responseFromServer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about this, your question is "What is wrong using Async and ***Await*** in this WPF example?" please point to me the line that uses `await`.

Comment: `WebRequest` is a little heavy weight, you can replace all of `RetrieveContent()` with `public async Task<string> RetrieveContent() { using(var wc = new WebClient()) { return await wc.DownloadStringAsync(Url); } }` then edit GetStringPrice to start with `var html = await RetrieveContent();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code right now has many issues, first of all you need your event handler to be `async` so that you can await on your method which is returning `Task<int>`, secondly you can set message Loading before calling method and await it so that it waits for that method to complete it's and when it will complete working returning result then set message to Done:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     lblStatus.Content = "Loading...";
     int bitcoinPriceTask = await GetBitcoinPrice();
     lblStatus.Content = "Done";

}

protected async Task<int> GetBitcoinPrice()
{
     IPriceRetrieve bitcoin = new BitcoinPrice();
     string price = await bitcoin.GetStringPrice();
     txtResult.Text = price;
     return 1;
}
```

or more better can be returning `Task<string>` and set the TextBox value there in event handler:

```
protected async Task<string> GetBitcoinPrice()
{
    IPriceRetrieve bitcoin = new BitcoinPrice();
    string price = await bitcoin.GetStringPrice();
    return price;
}
```

and in event handler:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     lblStatus.Content = "Loading...";
     string price = await GetBitcoinPrice();
     txtResult.Text = price;
     lblStatus.Content = "Done";

}
```

Comment: In your "better version" you could also throw in a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on `GetStringPrice()` because you no-longer touch the UI inside the `GetBitcoinPrice()` method.

Comment: thanks, not sure if I missed something but it still locks the ui

Comment: @ThePoet the thing you likely missed is `BitcoinPrice.GetStringPrice()` needs to also return a `Task<string>`. The entire method chain should be async till you get to the network call you are making to find the price. (You also could wrap it in a `Task.Run(` but making the call chain async to the network call is the much better option)

Comment: @ThePoet what is the implemetation of ``GetBitcoinPrice()``?

Comment: so if I wanted the methods of my classes to be able to use awaitAsync from who is consuming it, I always have to change the signature to Task<something> ?

Comment: @ThePoet yes, till you get to code you did not write that returns a `Task<Somthign>` for example you likely are using `WebClient.DownloadString(` which returns a `string`, you would change your code to call `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(` which returns a `Task<string>` then you would await on that task in your function.

Comment: yes, you have to, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063520/how-do-you-create-an-async-method-in-c

Comment: I added the BitcoinPrice code in my question, as requested

Comment: @ThePoet you have to make that method async as well

Comment: thank you. Very stupid question(maybe): Isn't there a wait to inject the method will be using await/async?

Comment: You would replace `var response = request.GetResponse();` with `var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();` then make the whole rest of the chain async, awaiting as needed.