# Making a normal method asynchronous in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a method in c#:

```
public DataSet OpenSqlQuery(string SqlQuery)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
    con.Open();
    var sqlc = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlc);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Now I want to make it as an asynchronous method so I can call it by `await`. so I changed it to:

```
public async Task<DataSet> OpenSqlQuery(string SqlQuery)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
    con.Open();
    var sqlc = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlc);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    await da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

I set `await` before `da.Fill(ds)` because at this line, the program waits for server. But the function shows this error:

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension
>   method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I make this method asynchronous?

P.S: The main goal is to call this method as follows:

```
Dataset ds = await objConnect.OpenSqlQuery(query);
```

P.S: Difference between this question and possible dupplicated one is that this post about making an existing synchronous method to asynchronous, while another is about making an asynchronous method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create an asynchronous method in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063520/how-do-you-create-an-asynchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: No. It is different.

Comment: Look at the `Task` class, f.e.[`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As a side-note: you should use the `using`-statement to dispose the connection as soon as you're finished with it. I would not store it in a field of the class.

Comment: @Tim, As I found, `Task.Run` is used when we wait for our program to end, not other programs. isn't it?

Comment: @Tim, Because I want to remain the form responsive during the query executes.

Comment: Isn't Fill going to be called sychronously anyway? Why not use SqlDataReader and get Access to Reader.ReadAsync and SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync ? Then you can do Async properly.

Comment: @Stuart, `Fill` is the main time consuming method in this function. when I made it synchronous, what is the benefit of `async`?

Comment: Really is it necessary to bring `await` before `Fill....`?

Comment: @Ernis - `async` methods construct the `Task` wrapper automatically. Seriously, this feature has existed for a fair few years now.

Comment: It should also be noted that this method, in general, represents a bit of an anti-pattern. You're forcing callers to only work in terms of a string query and so precluding any use of parameters, opening yourself if for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @AmirZojaji: Is this running in a UI context, as part of an ASP.NET request, or in a background thread?

Comment: @Stephen, This is inside a UI and I need `await` to make the form responsive during query execution.

Comment: @AmirZojaji: In that case, the `Task.Run` solution is appropriate.